# Query with more than 192 parameters never completes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

*For the curious, I discovered this problem because of queries generated by Entity Framework, but I've reproduced it by running ordinary SQL commands through SSMS.*

**Summary:** I'm running a simple query that checks for existing data by querying against the composite primary key. If I run a parameterized version of query that has 193 or more parameters, the query never finishes (I waited for 5 minutes before canceling). If I run a similar query with 192 or fewer parameters, it completes almost instantly, as expected of a primary key lookup.

**Background:** I have the following table with a clustered composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable {
    KeyCol1 INT NOT NULL,
    KeyCol2 INT NOT NULL,
    KeyCol3 INT NOT NULL,
    OtherCol1 INT NOT NULL,
    OtherCol2 INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (KeyCol1 ASC, KeyCol2 ASC, KeyCol3 ASC)
}
```

This table currently has ~52 million rows in it. If I want to check for the existence of one particular row, I might do this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE KeyCol1 = 100 AND KeyCol2 = 200 AND KeyCol3 = 300
```

This returns near-instantly whether or not a matching row is found. If I want to check for the existence of several different rows, and return which ones were found, I would have to `OR` together several conditions:

```
SELECT KeyCol1, KeyCol2, KeyCol3 FROM MyTable 
WHERE (KeyCol1 = 100 AND KeyCol2 = 200 AND KeyCol3 = 300)
   OR (KeyCol1 = 101 AND KeyCol2 = 201 AND KeyCol3 = 301)
   OR ...
```

This also returns near-instantly, even if I have over 300 different rows I'm looking for.

**Problem:** If I take the exact same query but pull the values out into parameters, the query never finishes:

```
DECLARE @val1 INT = 100;
DECLARE @val2 INT = 200;
DECLARE @val3 INT = 300;
DECLARE @val4 INT = 101;
DECLARE @val5 INT = 201;
DECLARE @val6 INT = 301;
...
SELECT KeyCol1, KeyCol2, KeyCol3 FROM MyTable 
WHERE (KeyCol1 = @val1 AND KeyCol2 = @val2 AND KeyCol3 = @val3)
   OR (KeyCol1 = @val4 AND KeyCol2 = @val5 AND KeyCol3 = @val6)
   OR ...
```

I started bisecting the number of parameters until I discovered that 192 seems to be the magic number. Using the query above with up to 192 parameters works fine, it returns almost as quickly as having the values hard-coded inline (there is a small performance hit of a few milliseconds). However, as soon as I add a 193rd parameter to the query, it chokes.

**My question**: Is this known, accepted behavior or is it some kind of bug? If it's accepted behavior then what options do I have to try and work around it? Inlining the parameter values works, though it's a suboptimal solution for me (I have to hack Entity Framework to force it not to use parameterized queries).

**Edit -- A partial answer**: As @JoeW suggested, I compared the execution plans of the queries with 192 parameters and 193 parameters, and they are indeed different. For 192 parameters, [the execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp6Rp.jpg) is basically 64 `INDEX SEEK`s (one per row) that are `MERGE JOIN`ed together. At 193 parameters, [the execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhCv6.jpg) switches to a single `INDEX SCAN` and then `FILTER`s the results. Very interesting. Running the same query with all the values inlined produces [an execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCtaF.jpg) that just does an `INDEX SEEK` only, no `JOIN`s or `SCAN`s.

So the problem isn't strictly related to the number of parameters, but rather the number of index seeks, but it's only a problem for parameterized queries. Very interesting indeed.

Comment: Well your first mistake is the compound key in a large table, your next mistake is using Entity Framework to do any thing at all complex because tuning it is a problem and it writes truly atrociaous code(especially if you need OR conditions which tend to be slower (unions tend to work much faster) and your third mistake is liekly to be parameter sniffing. Removing the paraters woudl be a mistake opening you up to security problems. Rewrite the SQl in a stored proc and call that from Entity Framework.

Comment: @HLGEM Did you read the question? He said everything you said. He pointed out that he reproduced the issue in SQL *without* EF. He said that removing the parameters would be sub-optimal. Reading comprehension FAIL!

Comment: @HLGEM "Well your first mistake is the compound key in a large table". Not a mistake. Those three columns are the only values that consumers will have access to. Even if I create an arbitrary `IDENTITY` column and use it as the primary key, consumers will still have to look up values using `KeyCol1, KeyCol2, KeyCol3`, but now they'll be querying against a non-clustered index. I will have worsened my position.

Comment: @HLGEM "your next mistake is using Entity Framework". Not relevant. I pointed out in the first sentence that I can reproduce the issue purely in SQL, and that EF is simply how I stumbled upon the problem.

Comment: @HLGEM "Removing the paraters woudl be a mistake opening you up to security problems." I'm aware, that's why I explicitly called it a workaround and called it a suboptimal solution.

Comment: @HLGEM "Rewrite the SQl in a stored proc and call that from Entity Framework." How would I pass a list of triples to that stored procedure? XML?

Comment: @ean5533 If you have to pass a list into a stored procedure, you might want to look at using [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.105).aspx).  This lets you pass an array into the stored procedure to be used.

Comment: @bluefeet A good idea. EF unfortunately doesn't support table-valued parameters, but If I decide to move away from EF (which is a possibility) then that will be the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: Or you can pass in a comma delimted list and split it out to a temp table in the SP.

Comment: Have you tried running an explain plan with 192 and 193 parameters and see what changes? It could just be an issue of how the database is trying to run the query when you add in the 193rd paramater

Comment: @JoeW Good intuition. When I jump from 192 to 193, the **estimated** execution plan changes from doing 64 index seeks (one per row) that are MERGED together, to doing a single index scan and then a filter. I finally just got it to finish after running for 12 minutes, and the actual execution plan matches the estimated.

Comment: Glad it helped, I suggested it because I have run into that situation in the past where changing part of the where clause such as widening the date range has drastically changed the performance of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a temp table for all variables with 3 columns as `val1, val2, val3` and join these two tables you will get your answer.

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable {
    ColumnId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Col1 INT NOT NULL,
    Col2 INT NOT NULL,
    Col3 INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TempTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ColumnId)
}
```

Insert all variables data into table.

```
INSERT INTO TempTable (Col1, Col2, Col3) 
VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3), (@val4, @val5, @val6), ...
```

Run this query:

```
SELECT t1.KeyCol1, t1.KeyCol2, t1.KeyCol3 
FROM MyTable t1 
INNER JOIN TempTable t2 ON t1.KeyCol1 = t2.Col1 AND t1.KeyCol2 = t2.Col2 AND t1.KeyCol3 = t2.Col3
```

Comment: While an interesting alternative, this doesn't really answer the question of whether or not the paramaterized query performance is a known issue.

Comment: @Tyrsius It does present one possible workaround (which is the second question I asked). Unfortunately this alternative doesn't work well for me. In order to use a temp table I would have to create a stored procedure, but I have no way of passing a list of triples to the stored procedure (unless I pass XML and parse it with SQLXML).

Comment: Following up on my own comment, @bluefeet commented above that I could use a table-valued parameter. It won't work in EF (which I'm currently using) but it's something to consider.

Comment: +1, if you don't want to use a temp table, then replace the temp table with a derived table where you SELECT key1, key2, key3 UNION select key1, key2, key3 union select...

Answer (score 0):

How long have you let it run? I've encountered issues where the query plan is too complex to be generated. I'd check to see if you get the same error after letting it run for a bit. A workaround is to break up the queries into smaller batches

```
SELECT KeyCol1, KeyCol2, KeyCol3 FROM MyTable 
WHERE (KeyCol1 = @val1 AND KeyCol2 = @val2 AND KeyCol3 = @val3)

UNION ALL

SELECT KeyCol1, KeyCol2, KeyCol3 FROM MyTable 
WHERE (KeyCol1 = @val4 AND KeyCol2 = @val5 AND KeyCol3 = @val6)

UNION ALL ...
```

Comment: I finally got it to finish after running for 12 minutes. As @JoeW suggested above in the comments, I checked the execution plans between 192 and 193, and it appears that at 193 parameters the execution plan changes.